# Upgrade PhoneGap to Cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

can I upgrade phonegap to cordova via npm/node.js? I am having issues with installing cordova

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

I believe the problem maybe associated with the fact phonegap is already installed.

Comment: I have both installed and didn't get any error

Comment: To Help,people need to know what is the error you are facing.